# Using Amazon SES for 2 domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I currently have one AWS account with 2 ec2 instances for 2 different domains (websites) I have set up. Previously, I verified one of the domains, created an IAM user for it and lodged a successful request to remove the account from the sandbox. Now I wish to use SES for the other domain as well. I know how to set up different MAIL FROM domains for the 2 domains, but in terms of code, the access and secret key I generate from creating new IAM users (which then get used in code) do not seem to take into account the different domains. Is it possible to use AWS SES for two separate domains like this (where the emails sent from each app have different MAIL FROM domains), and if so how does the code know which domain the emails are being sent? Is there a way to somehow link the IAM user to the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does the code know which domain the emails are being sent?

The code you are writing has to know the `FROM` email address it is using. That's how your code knows which domain it is sending email with.

> Is there a way to somehow link the IAM user to the domain?

This is well documented under the [Controlling access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/control-user-access.html) section of the official AWS SES documentation. Specifically under the "Restricting the From Address" section:

> The following policy permits a user to call the Amazon SES
> email-sending APIs, but only if the "From" address is
> marketing@example.com.
>
> ```
> {
>   "Version":"2012-10-17",
>   "Statement":[
>     {
>       "Effect":"Allow",
>       "Action":[
>         "ses:SendEmail",
>         "ses:SendRawEmail"
>       ],
>       "Resource":"*",
>       "Condition":{
>         "StringEquals":{
>           "ses:FromAddress":"marketing@example.com"
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

You would use conditions in the IAM policy to restrict a role to only sending emails with certain `FROM` email addresses.

Comment: In one of my apps, users create accounts with their email and the ses emails are sent from the email address they sign up with (after the email address is verified). The verified emails aren't necessarily associated with a domain - how would the including the from email indicate which of the apps the email is originated?

Comment: Are those user email addresses being added to SES as verified addresses?

Comment: yes - doing it manually via console, but will eventually use the api to automate EDIT: when I say the verified emails aren't necessarily associated with a domain, I mean the domain of my two apps, not things like gmail, yahoo etc.

Comment: Then you can't really add a restriction to the `FromAddress` for that app in the IAM policy. Also, you keep asking things like how the code would know the domain, or "how would the including the from email indicate which of the apps the email is originated". That seems not related to AWS IAM. You assign your IAM permissions to an EC2 instance, and the code running on that instance will then be able to do the things allowed in that IAM policy, but that doesn't configure your code with knowledge about email domains. Configuring your code is something that happens separately from AWS IAM.

Comment: So if I set up 2 mail from domains, one for each verified app (this is not the FromAddress/sender email, the mail from domain I am talking about is set by going to the SES console, clicking domains on the left pane, clicking on one of the verified domains and editing the mail from domain towards the bottom) how is it controlled which mail from domain is used when sending an email?

Comment: The `FROM` email address contains a domain name. SES will pick the verified domain that matches the `FROM` address.

Comment: But in my app the sender emails can be any email the user signs up with e.g. john.smith54@gmail.com - if this is the ```FROM``` email address (where I presume the domain name you're talking about is gmail) how would it be decided that this email is associated with the domain of the app/how would it be decided that the app's domain is where the email originated?

Comment: If the sending email is `john.smith54@gmail.com` then it doesn't use your sending domain at all, because that sending domain doesn't match. Instead it would use the verified email address that you are currently manually verifying, that is separate from the verified domain. Every email sent by SES has to match either a verified domain, or a verified email. You seem to be looking for some sort of connection between email domains and specific applications that does not exist.

Comment: ok right I think I get it - thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

With Amazon Lightsail (virtual linux servers,) I have two servers (instances) each with it's own domain name. One of my sites was sending messages using the other site's domain name. What seems to have fixed the problem for me was creating **two IAM groups and two IAM users**, putting one user in each group, and assigning smtp verified identities from each domain name to unique IAM users - one IAM user for each domain name. (As originally I was using the same IAM user/group for both domain names.) And unless I am incorrect, there was a sort order selection of which verified email address to use, or a cached use. I didn't verify my domains, only an email address from each domain name. But both virtual servers could see both of the verified email addresses (from both of the domain names.) Splitting into two IAM groups / two IAM users, using one IAM user for each domain name verified smtp identity, resolved my problem.